# Зацикливание при рекурсивном обходе каталогов

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, процесс, g++

Пишу приложение которое работает с **процессами** **pid** и **pipe**.
Программа ищет файлы заканчивающиеся на знак **"~"** в **каталоге** + во всех **подкаталогах** которые есть в этом **каталоге**.
После компиляции,запускается программа и зависает, как будто не выходит из цикла.
Не понимаю в чем проблема.
Компилирую через **g++** на **ubuntu** **18.04**
Постарался как можно больше добавить комментариев для разборки кода.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <vector>

struct PipeList 
{
  int fadr[2];
  pid_t pid;
};

struct result
{
   int count;
   char dir[4096];
};


int GetDir()
{
  std::vector<pid_t>    head;               //Список с номерами дочерних процессов
  std::vector<struct PipeList> pipeList;    //Вспомогательный список с дочерними процессами
  char path[4096]=".";                    //Основна папка
  errno = 0;
  DIR *dfd;                             //Переменная дескриптора папки
  struct result mainRes;                    //Основная структура с результатом
  strcpy(mainRes.dir, path);
  mainRes.count = 0;                        //Начальное  количество файлов
  struct stat inf;                      //Информация о файле/каталоге
  struct dirent *dp;                        //Переменная дескриптора каталога

pid_t pid;                              //Переменная с дочерним процессом
int status;                             //Переменная статуса процесса
int lpipe;                              //Вспомогательная переменная с номером процесса

if((dfd = opendir(path)) != NULL)
{

    while((dp=readdir(dfd)) != NULL)
    {
        //printf("\nPID - %d",getpid());
        char file_name[4096];               //Название файла
        char b_path[4096];                  //Полный путь с название файла

        strcpy(file_name, dp->d_name);
        strcpy(b_path, path);
        strcat(b_path, "/");
        strcat(b_path, file_name);          
        
        if(stat(b_path,&inf) == 0)
        {
            if(S_ISREG(inf.st_mode))
            {
                //Обработка файла                                   
               if (b_path[strlen(b_path)-1] == '~')
               {
                   mainRes.count++;
                   strcpy(mainRes.dir,path);    
                   printf("\nПуть - %s\n",b_path);
               }                            
                
                            
            }
            else if(S_ISDIR(inf.st_mode)!=0 && (strcmp(file_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(file_name, "..") != 0))
            {
                //Проверка на каталог
                //и создание процессов
                if(pipeList.size() == 0)
                {
                    //Создание новой трубы в родительском процессе                          
                    //Запись в список с трубами
                    struct PipeList localStruct;
                    lpipe = pipe(localStruct.fadr); 
                    pipeList.push_back(localStruct); 
                }
                else
                {
                    //Запись номера текущего процесса 
                    //в последний элемент списка
                    //Создание нового элемента списка
                    //Запись в новый элемент трубы
                    //Запись в последний элемент списка,
                    //что это дочерний процесс
                    pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].pid = getpid();
                    struct PipeList localStruct;
                    localStruct.pid = 0;
                    lpipe = pipe(localStruct.fadr);
                    pipeList.push_back(localStruct);     
                }

                if(lpipe == 0)
                {
                    
                    //Создаем дочерний процесс
                    pid = fork();
                                        
                    if(pid > 0)
                    {
                        //Это родительский процесс
                        //Заносим в конец списка 
                        //номер дочернего процесса 
                        head.push_back(pid);
                    }
                    else if(pid == 0)
                    {
                        
                        //Это дочерний процесс
                        //Передача в основную переменную директории
                        //нового пути
                        //Открыть папку на чтение
                        //Проверка на успех
                        //Очистка унаследованного списка
                        mainRes.count = 0;
                        strcpy(path, b_path);                           
                        dfd = opendir(path);
                        if (dfd == NULL) printf("\n 125 Ошибка - %s", strerror(errno)); 
                        head.clear();       
                    }
                    else if(pid == -1)
                    {
                        if(errno != 0) printf("\n 130 Ошибка - %s", strerror(errno));       
                    }
                }
                else if(lpipe == -1) printf("\n 133 Ошибка - %s", strerror(errno));  
            }   
        }
        else if(errno) printf("\n 136 Ошибка - %s", strerror(errno)); 
        
    }
    if(errno!=0) printf("\n 140 Ошибка - %s Путь - %s",strerror(errno),path);
    closedir(dfd);  
    
    //Обработка дочерних процессов
    pid_t s;
    //printf("head.size = %zu\n",head.size());
    int headsize = head.size()-1;
    for(int iter=headsize; iter>=0;iter--)
    {

        //printf("\n Процесс - %d -",getpid());
        //Проверить (возможны ошибки сегментации)
    
        s = waitpid(head[iter], &status, 0);
        if (s == -1) printf("\n 154 Ошибка - %s", strerror(errno));  
        else if(s >= 0)
        if(!WIFEXITED(status))
        {
            printf("\n Status: %d ERROR: %s\n",status,strerror(errno)); 
        }
        else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
        {
            printf("Process %d terninated with term signal\n",pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].pid);
        }
        else if(WTERMSIG(status))
        {
            printf("Process %d terninated with term signal\n",pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].pid)
        }
        else if(WCOREDUMP(status))
        {
            printf("Process %d terninated with core dump\n",pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].pid)
        }               
    }
    //Передача значений из дочерних процессов 
    //в родительский
    if(pid == 0)
    {   
        
        //Закрыть трубу в дочернем процессе на чтение
        if(close(pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].fadr[0]) == 0)
        {   
            
            //Запись значений, т.е. 
            //передача в родительский процесс
            if(write(pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].fadr[1],&mainRes,sizeof(result)) > 0)
                //Закрыть трубу в дочернем процессе на запись
                if(close(pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].fadr[1])<0) printf("\n 174 Ошибка - %s\n", strerror(errno));  
        }
        else printf("\n  176Ошибка - %s\n", strerror(errno));           
    }
    else if(pid > 0)
    {
        
        //Проматриваем все дочерние процессы, 
        //которые мы создали в текущем родительском процессе
        
        while(pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].pid == 0)
        {
            struct result bufres;
            //Производим чтение переданных
            //значений из дочернего 
            
            if(read(pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].fadr[0],&bufres,sizeof(result)) >= 0)
            {   
                //Закрыть трубу на чтение
                if(close(pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].fadr[0])<0) printf("\n 193 Ошибка - %s\n", strerror(errno));   
                //Сравнение сзначений
                if(bufres.count > mainRes.count) mainRes = bufres;
                //Закрыть трубу на запись
                if(close(pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].fadr[1])<0) printf("\n 197 Ошибка - %s\n", strerror(errno)); 
                //Удаление последнего 
                //(т.к. это труба для взаимодействия
                // с дочерним процессом) элемента списка
                printf("\npipeList.pid = %d\n, Путь - %s",pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].pid,path);
                if(pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].pid == 0) pipeList.pop_back();
            }
            else
            {
              printf("\n 206 Ошибка - %s PID - %d", strerror(errno),getpid());          
            }
            //printf("\npipelist.size = %zu\n",pipeList.size());
            //printf("\npipelist.pid = %d\n",pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].pid);

        }
        //printf("\nPid - %d\n",pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].pid);               
        //Проверка на конец списка
        //т.е. остались ли трубы
        //printf("\npipeList.size = %zu\n",pipeList.size());
        if(pipeList.size() != 0)
        {
            //Проверка на то, что мы находимся 
            //в дочернем процессе, а не в корневом
            //printf("\nПроцесс - %d PID - %d\n",pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].pid,getpid());
            if(pipeList.size()>1)
            {

                
                //Передаем из дочернего процесса
                //(который сейчас является родительским)
                //значения

                //Закрыть трубу на чтение
                if(close(pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].fadr[0]) == 0)
                {       
                            
                    //Запись значений                       
                    if (write(pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].fadr[1],&mainRes,sizeof(result)) > 0)
                    {
                        if(close(pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].fadr[1])<0) printf("\n 234 Ошибка - %s", strerror(errno));  
                    }
                    else printf("\n 236 Ошибка - %s", strerror(errno));  
                }
                else printf("\n 238 Ошибка - %s", strerror(errno)); 
            }
            else 
            {
                                    
                
                //Корневой процесс

                struct result bufres;
                //Чтение значений из дочерних процессов 
                //printf("\nPIPELISTSIZE - %zu\n",pipeList.size());         
                if(read(pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].fadr[0],&bufres,sizeof(result)) >= 0)
                {   
                    
                    //printf("\nPIPELISTSIZE - %zu\n",pipeList.size());         
                    
                    //Закрыть трубу на чтение
                    if(close(pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].fadr[0])<0) printf("\n 253 Ошибка - %s\n", strerror(errno));       
                    //Сравнение значений из дочених процессов с 
                    //корневым-родительским
                    if(bufres.count > mainRes.count) mainRes = bufres;
                    //Закрыть трубу на запись
                    if(close(pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].fadr[1])<0) printf("\n 258 Ошибка - %s\n", strerror(errno)); 
                    //Удаление последней трубы (последнего элемента списка)
                    if(pipeList[pipeList.size()-1].pid == 0) pipeList.pop_back();
                    
                }
                else printf("\n Ошибка - %s\n", strerror(errno)); 
                printf("\nРезультат:\nКаталог -  %s Количество файлов со знаком ~ - %d\n", mainRes.dir, mainRes.count);
            }
        }           
    }
    
    if(errno != 0) printf("\n Ошибка - %s\n", strerror(errno)); 

   
}
else printf("\n Ошибка - %s", strerror(errno)); 
return 0;
}

int main()
{

  GetDir();
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Метки `c++` и `g++` - используйте стандартное решение `<filesystem>` - код сократится в разы.

Comment: почему бы просто не запустить это дело в любой ide и не посмотреть где он зависает? Да хоть printf расставить и посмотреть что в консоль напишет, вот в чем прикол спрашивать это тут?

Comment: так я проходил принтфами по всему коду, энивэй ничего не понятно из этого. Подумал может кто то, что то похожее писал и натыкался на такую проблему и знает как её решить. . .

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Comment: `stat` принимает только полный путь, а вы даёте начиная с точки `.\filename`. Пишите начиная не с точки а с `getcwd(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

`stat` принимает только полный путь, а вы даёте начиная с точки `.\filename`. Пишите начиная не с точки а с `getcwd(...)`.